# How to delete a comment on a card in Trello

Tags: delete, trello

After I add a comment on a Trello card, I could not find the delete button. How do I delete comments from a Trello card?

Answer (score 8):

On October 13, [Trello added support for deleting comments](https://trello.com/card/board/delete-comments/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c/4e70e330363091000009f6c3).  There is now a "Delete" link under comments that you made.  On boards with public commenting enabled, board members can delete public comments.

**However**, this does not apply to *copied cards* as pointed out by [Davide](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/18944/how-to-delete-a-comment-on-a-card-in-trello#comment89218_18946).

Comment: But that does not work for copied cards, or for comments that you have not created yourself (even if you are board administrator). Big bummer!

Answer (score 0):

> ### Editing & Deleting
>
> Edit or delete comments by clicking the "edit" or "delete" links beneath the comment. You can edit or delete any comment you make on any board. Board admins can delete comments made by any non admins on their boards. Deleting a comment is permanent.
>
> [image]
>
> Click "Edit" or "Delete" to edit or delete a comment.

[Source](http://help.trello.com/article/765-commenting-on-cards).