# How can I change the due date for a card?

Tags: trello

Once I have added a due date to a card by [adding a comment with a MM/DD/YYYY date](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/18947/how-do-i-assign-a-due-date-to-a-card-in-trello), is there any way I can change that?

The answer to [can I delete a comment?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/18944/how-to-delete-a-comment-on-a-card-in-trello) is currently "not yet" and editing comments is not possible either.  Will a new comment with a different date override the previously added date?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All you need to do is add another comment with a due date and it will override an existing due date.